# MySQL sum based on a condition

Tags: mysql, sum

I have data in a table which gives raw events and a count of products like this:

```
|order_id|customer_id|product_count|
|1       |1          |2            |
|2       |1          |-1           |
|3       |1          |3            |
|4       |1          |-1           |
|5       |2          |-1           |
|6       |2          |2            |
|7       |2          |-1           |
|8       |3          |-1           |
|9       |3          |-1           |
|10      |3          |-1           |
```

I want results like this:  (Only sum values after the first positive value)

```
|customer_id|SUM(remaining_product)|
|1          |3                     |
|2          |1                     |
|3          |0                     |
```

Using this query I can return all of the sums:

```
SELECT customer_id, SUM(product_count) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

What I need is a runing sum of product_count, which should only start after a positive value.
So in case of customer 1, the first order is postiive so its 2-1+3-1=3
For cutomer 2 , first order is negative so ignore it , it will start with 2-1=1
For customer 3 , we never see a positive value so we stay at 0.

Comment: I don't think your result set is right. The sum for customer_id 2 is 0.

Comment: I have editied the question to better explain what I am trying to do. The sum of customer 2 is 1 as first order under it is negative.

Comment: Oh I understand now. I'm sorry, that was a lot trickier the second time around, but I was able to match your result set. Please see the edit to my answer.

Comment: did you end up solving this one?

Answer (score 1):

I approached this by starting with a subquery that retrieves the minimum positive row for each customer id. Simple enough using the MIN() function:

```
SELECT MIN(order_id) AS minOrderID, customer_id
FROM myTable
WHERE product_count > 0
GROUP BY customer_id
```

Then I joined that with the original table to get the rows on or after that order_id for each group. This way you can sum all rows beginning after the positive row. The query then becomes this:

```
SELECT t.customer_id, SUM(t.product_count)
FROM myTable t
JOIN (SELECT MIN(order_id) AS minOrderID, customer_id
  FROM myTable
  WHERE product_count > 0
  GROUP BY customer_id) w
ON w.customer_id = t.customer_id AND t.order_id >= w.minOrderID
GROUP BY t.customer_id;
```

You have to join the tables on the customer_id (naturally) but also on the condition that the order_id is greater than or equal to the minimum order_id with a positive product count. That way only the rows after that are summed.

If you aren't concerned with customer_ids that are 0, this query is enough. However, if you want 0 rows to show as well, I would do an outer join with a query that pulls each of the customer IDs. You will need an IFNULL() function to check for customer_ids that do not have a row in the second query above.

Finally, we have this:

```
SELECT k.customer_id, IFNULL(f.productSUM, 0) AS sumOfProducts
FROM(SELECT DISTINCT customer_id
     FROM myTable) k
LEFT JOIN(SELECT t.customer_id, SUM(t.product_count) AS productSUM
          FROM myTable t
          JOIN (SELECT MIN(order_id) AS minOrderID, customer_id
                FROM myTable
                WHERE product_count > 0
                GROUP BY customer_id) w
                ON w.customer_id = t.customer_id AND t.order_id >= w.minOrderID
                GROUP BY t.customer_id) f
ON k.customer_id = f.customer_id;
```

And believe it or not this works. Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/caa15f/22).

Answer (score 1):

The idea here is to calculate first positive (when `product_count > 0`) `order_id` for each customer and then sum `product_count` values for which `order_id >= first_positive_order_id`:

```
SELECT t.customer_id, SUM(
  CASE WHEN m.first_positive_order_id IS NOT NULL
        AND t.order_id >= m.first_positive_order_id
       THEN t.product_count
       ELSE 0
  END) as remaining_count
FROM `table` t
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT customer_id, MIN(order_id) AS first_positive_order_id
     FROM `table`
     WHERE product_count > 0
     GROUP BY customer_id
) m ON m.customer_id = t.customer_id
GROUP BY customer_id
```

Test it: [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/684bd6/1)

Comment: I like this a lot. Way cleaner than what I came up with, but similar thought process.

Answer (score 0):

```
select customer_id, 
       case when sum(product_count) < 0 
            then 0 
            else sum(product_count) 
       end as sum
from table 
group by customer_id;
```